# Zend Framework and fuelphp

Tags: zend-framework, fuelphp

I wanted to know if it was possible to use zend framework libraries from zend 1.11 in fuelphp? fuel looks nice and I started looking at it as I believe its the next logical step for any CI developer.

Is there any site or a howto for using zend library with fuel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what portions of Zend Framework you want to use. Some parts, e.g. Zend_View are tied into the MVC-part of the framework, but components like Zend_Pdf or Zend_Service_* have only few dependencies and should work fine in other frameworks as well.

What you should do is check out the [Reference Manual to see what other components are required by the component you are trying to use](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html#requirements.dependencies). And then put them in a library folder. Alternatively, just put the whole Zend Framework in a folder if you don't mind carrying the dead weight with you.

I've been using ZF-components standalone and found that it's useful to add it to include_path as you would when using ZF as MVC-framework, because some ZF-classes are instantiated dynamically, i.e. not via `require_once` and that won't work without the folder containing Zend/ being in the include_path.

Finally you have to add the folder to your autoloader, this should be as easy as:

```
Autoloader::add_namespace('Zend', __DIR__.'/path/to/Zend/library');
```

Comment: I let fuel go, I find it still lacking a lot of core features that would peel me away from Codeigniter. Thought y'all should know